# Testing component methods in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, mocha.js, enzyme

I cant understand why this is not working...

I am trying to test this function:

```
  export class Main extends React.Component {

  handleName = (name) => (value) => {
   const prevState = this.state[name]
   this.setState({ [name]: {...prevState, name: value } })
  }

 render(){
   return(
     //some things
   )
 }
}
```

and my test is (in mocha):

```
it('expects handleName to have been called on change', () => {
  wrapper.find('.teamInput').at(0).simulate('change');
  expect(wrapper.instance().handleName().called).to.equal(true);
});
```

I thought this was the correct way to test. I get an error saying: `expected undefined to equal true`

also when I `console.log(wrapper.instance().handleName())` it says it is a function, so it knows that it is there....

my beforeEach:

```
describe('Main Component', () => {
  let wrapper;
  const teamsStub = [];
  const matchesStub = [];
  const submitMatchStub = sinon.spy();
  const syncFirebaseToStoreStub = sinon.spy();
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(
      <Main
        teams={teamsStub}
        matches={matchesStub}
        submitMatch={submitMatchStub}
        syncFirebaseToStore={syncFirebaseToStoreStub}
      />
    )
  })
```

Comment: Have you rendered your component in the unit test?

Comment: handleName is component's local function and there is no spy for that function. that is not correct way of testing your code. If you are calling submitMatchStub on change then you can check if that is called or not.

Comment: You should test the behaviour of `handleChange`, so you should simulate changes on whatever calls it and check that the component's state has been updated to the simulated value e.g.: expect(`wrapper.state('your name').toEqual('your value') . Also, assuming your render() uses that state change, you should check the rendered value: `expect(wrapper.find('#myDiv').text()).toEqual('my value'));

Comment: cheers @dashton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
expect(wrapper.instance().handleName().called).to.equal(true);
```

The `called` method is only available on spies. So for example, you are passing in a spy for `submitMatch` to your component. If you try to test the workflow of wherever this method is used, there you can check if that method was called or not be calling `called` on the passed spy. But because `handleName` is an internal method in your component, you cannot spy it. So the above is invalid.

If you modify the code so that you pass `handleName` method from outside as prop. Then in your unit test, you can pass a sinon spy for it and verify it using `called`.

Comment: ah I see. but I want it local to the code at the moment. so is there no way to test component functions then? you have to extract them and pull them in as props? 

what am I doing differently to this guy: https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/208?

Comment: You can access the inner method that way, but it is still not a spy so you can't call `called` on it.